# How deep should be e2e Protractor tests?

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm writing e2e test for a login page and I realize I don't know how deep should be my test. I clarify myself: one main test has to be true login and, obviously, other one will be false login. Another tests can be checking existing links on login page work. But, should I test that all page's elements are displayed? E.g: writing a test to check a div and elements within are displayed:

```
it('It should be displayed a Elke Winter div', function(){

    var elkeDiv = angularPage.elkeDiv;
    expect(elkeDiv.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

    var title = angularPage.titleElke;
    var img = angularPage.imgElke;
    var content = angularPage.contentElke;
    var telephoneDt = angularPage.telDt;
    var telephoneDd = angularPage.telDd;
    var faxDt = angularPage.faxDt;
    var faxDd = angularPage.faxDd;

    expect(title.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    expect(img.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    expect(content.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    expect(telephoneDt.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    expect(telephoneDd.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    expect(faxDt.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    expect(faxDd.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
});
```

What do you think?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only test for page contents that are fundamental to the user experience, e.g.

- buttons
- text messages that indicates what's going on
- links
- inputs
- menus

Never test for html specific stuff like *div* but instead always use semantic selectors like html ids or classes or find them by content, e.g.

- `by.cssContainingText('#linkOne', 'Click here')`
- `by.buttonText('Send Email')`

If you find a `div` element that you want to target but has no html id nor html class then add it yourself whenever possible, i use a prefix `e2e-` like `e2e-linkOne` so developers know that the selector was identified with the purpose of testing. Then you target the element `$('.e2e-linkOne')` instead of by tagname and/or position `$$('div').get(2)`.